# Why wasn't Iron Man's armor a weak point in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie,

> Ultron infected tech of Avengers Tower just after his birth. It means he is capable of infecting tech. Also, if this wasn't the case, he could never be able to create his drones.

Just after its birth,

> He escaped using the Internet and infected digital devices across the entire planet. Again, awesome capability (think Skynet).

We also saw that

> Iron Man's armor was connected to the Internet. He googled for the keyword "Hulk" during flight just before he deployed Veronica.

Then, why did Ultron let Iron Man win the fight? Why didn't he simply hack Iron Man's armor to use him as own drone?

Answer (score 20):

It's probably safe to assume that, after the events of Iron Man 2 & 3, Tony made significant security upgrades to his Iron Man operating systems.

In [**Iron Man 2**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_2):

> Ivan Vanko was able to hack the systems of War Machine, controlling the armor and turning it against Tony. Rhodey only regained control after Black Widow did a full reboot of the armor's operating system.

Then later in [**Iron Man 3**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_3):

> the Iron Patriot armor was used by Savin to attack Air Force One and kidnap the President of the United States. This occurred despite the existing security protocols, which were intended to allow ***only*** Tony Stark and James Rhodes to use the suits.

Knowing Tony, these situations would most likely result in the design & implementation of a more advanced security and firewall system for the suits - something that would prevent any future cases of hostile takeovers or hack attempts.

Comment: And yet for the rest of his work, he runs foreign code in his production environment. Bloody 1%!

Answer (score 3):

One does not simply

> hack Iron Man’s armor

However, I think your question is based on a false premise. Do we actually see Ultron infecting

> digital devices of entire planet?

I think we only ever see him controlling Stark’s drones, which kind of makes sense, given that

> Ultron’s original purpose was to control these drones.

We do see him

> reading basically every bit of information in Stark’s databases

but after he escapes, I think he just uses

> the original escaped drone to get a drone factory, which he controls, going at the Hydra base.

He never controls anything else. Hence he can’t control Stark’s armor.

Comment: Ultron infected all devices on the planet. It has been stated clearly.

Comment: Also, he was shown deleting information from Avengers tower computers.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: “Ultron infected all devices on the planet. It has been stated clearly.” It should be pretty easy for you to point out *where* it was stated then? You’re quite right that he deleted information from Stark’s computers, but that was before he “escaped into the internet”, right?

Comment: Vision removed this infection from the Internet. This proves the point.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: I must be forgetting stuff from the movie. I don’t think that proves anything in particular though. Ultron didn’t manage to hack into the nuclear launch codes, right? Because J.A.R.V.I.S. was protecting them. So he wasn’t able to hack into everything.

Comment: Ultron failed to hack Nuclear Weapons because launch codes are continuously changed. It's another story that Tony hacked it when he was in High School.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: I don’t think so — Stark went to Oslo and came back with J.A.R.V.I.S., then used him to create the Vision, right?

Comment: What! JARVIS dumped itself to data banks when Ultron attacked it.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: maybe we need to re-watch the film together. But Stark came back from Oslo, and had a fairly involved conversation with Banner, explaining how he found JARVIS defending the nuke codes, and how they should use JARVIS against Ultron.

Comment: Speculating at this point, but if JARVIS can protect the nuclear codes, he can definitely shield 1 armor..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - My impression was that Ultron connected himself all over the planet via the internet, not that he *was* the internet and/or everything connected to it.